# How many non working people are on Obamacare?

Tags: united-states, affordable-care-act

I would like to know how many people utilizing Obamacare are not currently in the labor force. Is there a statistic covering this? A percentage perhaps.

Comment: Like kids?  The elderly and retired?  The disabled?  Students?  Veterans?  Be specific with what you mean.

Comment: "Not currently in the labor force" is a well defined term in official government labor statistics. It doesn't seem ambiguous to me. To the extent that there are different assumptions that could be made, pointing them out in an answer and clarifying how different assumptions would lead to a different answer would solve the problem.

Comment: @Venture2099, you left out drug addicts, people who make more gaming the system, unemployable criminals, etc, etc.

Comment: No I didn't.  I wasn't making an authoratitive list.

Answer (score 3):

Not many at all.

(This is assuming that spouses and children who are not in the workforce personally count as in the workforce is someone in their household is working - many working poor or middle class children and/or stay at home parents, perhaps 50%-67% of the total, get coverage through Obamacare in connection with a working father/mother/spouse).

Medicaid already covered people with incomes below the poverty line which most people who are unemployed are, and a lot of disabled people (some disabled people and retired people age 65+ were already covered by Medicare).

Obamacare (1) extended Medicaid to the working poor/working class/lower middle class, (2) subsidized health insurance in the private individual market place for middle class families who aren't part of group plans, and (3) encouraged employers who didn't have group plans to get them.

There would be some people who are early retirees or are independently wealthy and don't work who might qualify for subsidies, but this is probably a very small share of the total.

Most of the coverage gains were from Medicaid expansion for the working poor and low cost individual market plans that are subsidized. More affluent people usually had health insurance and under Obamacare paid less to get more from private health insurance in the individual market, rather than not having access to health care at all.

Comment: I would disagree with "not many at all" for the reasons you say.   Some people retire, others could be between jobs, on unemployment or temporarily in school.   People with savings would prefer to be insured, especially if they're older.    There's a percentage, not working but not yet on medicare and too well off for medicaid who like Obamacare cause it gives them a needed safety-net.   I have no idea on hard numbers though.